# Magento Admin 404 and Front End bare

Tags: magento2, localhost

After succesfully installing Magento 2.0 on my local server, going to the backend gives a 404 and the front end looks like its missing the css. Any ideas? Im not receiving any error messages other than 404.

Comment: whats your admin link? Are you sure have changed admin route during installation?

Answer (score 0):

Css and js will created at run time in pub/static folder
In first time page will look like broken reload the page

Even css and js error is showing or missing then run below command (I recommend run the command)

`php D:\xampp\htdocs\project_name\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy`

This will generate all static data in pub/static folder

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you enabled [Apache server rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

Install Composer.

Install magento.

Run command sudo php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy

Give user permission 777 to your magento root folder.

Delete cache from var/cache.